# Groupby using pandas the different row data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data set as follow:

```
Class     Students

Seven       10

Seven       15

Five        12

Two         23

Two         36

Ten         16

Ten         10

Ten         5
```

I need to group them by rows, and make manipulations further:

Required output:

```
Class   Total

Seven   10
        15

Five    12

Two     23
        36

Ten     16
        10
        5
```

I have just given a sample data, my actual data set is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [536]: df = df.groupby('Class').sum().reset_index() 

In [537]: df                                                                                                                                                         
Out[537]: 
   Class  Students
0   Five      12.0
1  Seven      25.0
2    Ten      31.0
3    Two      59.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = df.groupby('Class').sum()
print(df)

       Students
Class
Five         12
Seven        25
Ten          31
Two          59
```

Comment: I need to save it as a dataframe, so that further manipulation can be done

Comment: Look at the edit, it is already a dataframe just assign it to a variable